# contrasted if statements in java

Tags: java

I have been playing around with some code and noticed that if I have an if statement which kind of does the same thing twice, I was wondering whether java had any implementation to do the opposite of a certain action.

```
if(id == 1) {
   partnerID = 3;
} else if(id == 2) {
   partnerID = 4;
} else if (id == 3) {
   partnerID = 1;
} else {
   partnerID = 2;
}
```

As you can see, if id is 1 then the partner id is 3 and visa versa.

Comment: use a `switch` for starters.

Comment: well I know about switch statements, but its just has clunky and ugly @MohammedAoufZOUAG

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan that's a bit too complicated especially in this case.

Comment: @TheProgrammerG Removed the comment because it didn't really answer the question anyways. However, a Map approach would be much easier to read instead of the current answers IMO especially if there were to be more ids and partners as I mentioned.

Comment: Sorry I should have stated, there are only 4 ids max @GeorgeMulligan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, java doesn't have this kind of "opposite action". But you can do some simple math:

```
   if(id == 1 || id == 3){
       partnerID = 4 - id;
   }else if(id == 2 || id == 4){
       partnerID = 6 - id;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookup table.

```
private static final int[] ID_TO_PARTNER_ID = [ 2, 3, 4, 1 ];

static int partnerIdForId(int id) {
  return 0 <= id && id < ID_TO_PARTNER_ID.length
      ? ID_TO_PARTNER_ID[id]
      : 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is this deemed a more appropriate approach to the situation or is it something which is not really necessary.

Comment: I think this is a bit more complicated than needed.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG What the user is asking for is completely unclear.

Comment: @chrylis it's clear. The OP wants a clearer approach to the "ugly" if statements.

Comment: The original is more readable even if it has a couple of extra lines of code.

Comment: @chrylis it is perfectly clear. Personally the other answer makes more sense to me than this one. With this one, you need to attach a **JavaDoc** comment..

Comment: @MickMnemonic, there is a number of cases below which the `if else if` makes sense, and above which the lookup table makes sense.  When the case table exceeds a line, I would recommend putting the same number of entries on each line and using comments to make it easy to figure out which element is at a given index visually.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 and `Optional`, you can assign `partnerID` in a functional way. The `swap()` operation is encapsulated and parametrized, which eliminates duplication of numerical constants 1, 2, 3, 4. The problem though is to return both logical and numerical output of the operation. We have to know if a condition has been met, and we need the result of the swap. This could be done by returning `null`, but with `Optional` it becomes more elegant.

```
int partnerID = swap(1, 3, id).map(Optional::of)
       .orElse(swap(2, 4, id)).map(Optional::of)
       .orElse(Optional.of(defaultPartnerId)).get();

private static Optional<Integer> swap(int a, int b, int x) {
    if (x != a && x != b) return Optional.empty();
    return Optional.of(a + b - x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but way too complex for whats needed